# C#: DateTime.DayOfWeek to string comparison

Tags: c#, datetime

This code is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
string day = Thursday;
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

if (day == dt.DayOfWeek)
{
     // start the program
}
```

I need to read a day of the week value from a database, assign it to a string, then compare the string to dt.DayOfWeek to check if the program should execute.

My error is this: **"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DayOfWeek"**

Anyone know how to compare a string to a DateTime.DayOfWeek value?

Comment: objects in c# have a `.ToString()` method, most of the built-in ones actually parse the object inot a string

Comment: `I need to read a day of the week value from a database` what would return the DB. a number? or  a string?

Comment: The DB returns a string for the day value.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Easiest is to convert enum to string:

```
if (day == dt.DayOfWeek.ToString())...
```

Notes:

- if you can change type of `day` to `DayOfWeek` enum you can avoid string comparisons (and its related localization/comparison issues).
- if you have to use string make sure to decide if case is important or not (i.e. should  "thursday" be equal to `DayOfWeek.Thursday`) and use corresponding `String.Equals` method.
- consider converting string to enum with `Parse` as suggested in other answers: `((DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), day)`
- make sure incoming string is always English - if it could be in other languages you'll need to look into manually matching value to one provided in [CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.DayNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.daynames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: But is not a very good practice. It's better to check the equality with enums directy

Answer (score 16):

Use `Enum.Parse` to get the Enum value:

```
if ((DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), day) == dt.DayOfWeek)
```

If you're not sure it's a valid value, there's `TryParse<T>`:

```
Enum val;
if (Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>(day, out val) && val == dt.DayOfWeek)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.Thursday;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx):

```
string strDay = "Wednesday";
DayOfWeek day;
if (Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>(strDay, out day)
    && day == DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)
{
    // ...
}
```