# How to convert Specific string into a specific int

Tags: c#, arrays

I want convert the name of days in a week (Monday,Tuesday...) into the number of days in a week (Monday=1, Tuesday=2,...)

Comment: A google search for "c# convert string to dayofweek" found this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713366/c-datetime-dayofweek-to-string-comparison).

Comment: i would like to do it using the array method instead instead of the "if" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention using "array method".  Perhaps you mean looking up the index in a constant pre-defined array/collection.

```
public static int ConvertDayOfWeek(string day) {
    List<string> days = new List<string>{"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    return days.IndexOf(day);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enum.Parse` along with the `DayOfWeek` enum to parse a string that has a day of the week into an integer value (which is itself just a label that wraps an integer) that corresponds to the appropriate day of the week.  If you really need an integer specifically, and not an enum, you can cast that enum to an `int` to get its underlying value.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `enum` that contains all possible days, and then use `Enum.Parse` and cast it to an `int`. Though this is a bit of a "heavy hammer." Your other option is to use a `switch` or series of `if` statements to determine the number.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want for days of weeks is simple in c# using

```
int numberDate = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

which will give you the number of the day

```
string stringDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

which will give you the string name of the week.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

If you are going to have a structure which maps string to int, simply you may use `Dictionary<string,int>` like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> days = new Dictionary<string, int>();
days.Add("Monday",1);
days.Add("Tuesday",2);
//...

var number = days["Monday"];    //Result: 1
```