# how to match database day with calendar day in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select availability FROM doc_availabledays where dname='" + Label2.Text + "'", con);
DataSet dss = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(dss, "doc_availabledays");


DataRow drr = dss.Tables[0].Rows[0];
drr["availability"].ToString();

if (!e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dss.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if ((dr["availability"].ToString().Equals(DayOfWeek.Monday))||(dr["availability"].ToString().Equals(DayOfWeek.Tuesday))||(dr["availability"].ToString().Equals(DayOfWeek.Wednesday)))
        {

                e.Cell.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What help you need? Question isn't clear

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use the safe casting.

```
 string [] data = { "Monday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday" };
        DayOfWeek d;
        var dt = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (var st in data)
        {
            if (Enum.TryParse<DayOfWeek>(st, out d) && d == dt.DayOfWeek)
            {
                string abc = "i M Here";
            }
        }
```

It looks like you have multiple columns in the DataTable for `DayOfWeek`. If that's the case then use the same condition with multiple OR operators `||` or loop to the DataRow column as well.

For further details, take a look at this: [C#: DateTime.DayOfWeek to string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713366/c-datetime-dayofweek-to-string-comparison)