# Getting Just date of current Week given Day name string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to get Date only given I have string day name, So far I have tried this

```
var now = DateTime.Now.Date;

var currentDay = now.DayOfWeek;
int days = (int)currentDay+1;
dt1 = now.AddDays(-days);
dt1 = dt1.AddHours(hour);
```

example "Tuesday". Get todays date bc today is tuesday

But no luck

Comment: Some more info would be helpfull. What is your expected result for 01.01.2019 for example.

Comment: Can you give a sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Noname updated question

Comment: @Alex the hard part is *parsing* a localized day name into a `DayOfWeek`. Once you have that value you can calculate the difference in days between today and the target week day, eg `now.AddDays(thatDay - now.DayOfWeek)`. That of course assumes that weeks start on a Sunday and are calculated in a specific way

Comment: How do *you* define current week? Different people disagree on which day transition marks the boundary between weeks (E.g. Saturday -> Sunday or Sunday -> Monday being two conventions I'm seen)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever our week starts at sunday and end on Saturday

Answer (score 2):

base on

- [C#: DateTime.DayOfWeek to string comparison - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713366/c-datetime-dayofweek-to-string-comparison)
- [c# - How can I get the DateTime for the start of the week? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039/how-can-i-get-the-datetime-for-the-start-of-the-week)

  ```
      DateTime getDate(string dayOfWeekString)
      {
          var dayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), dayOfWeekString);
          var now = DateTime.Now.Date;
          var diff = (7 + (now.DayOfWeek - dayOfWeek)) % 7;
          return now.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;
      }
      Console.WriteLine(getDate("Tuesday"));
      Console.ReadLine();
  ```